# Split and select specific values from sqlserver table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table projects in SQL server having a field StartDate with values as

```
15-02-2013 15:02:40
20-08-2011 10:11:20
```

etc
From which i need to retrieve distinct year values like 
`2013 and 2011` only
I tried with queries like

```
select (case when charindex(' ', StartDate) > 0
             then left(StartDate, charindex(' ', (StartDate))-1)
             else StartDate
        end) as StartDate FROM [kneipp].[dbo].[kn_projects]
```

which gave result as **`15-02-2013 and 20-08-2011`**
and with

```
select (case when charindex('-', StartDate) > 0
             then right(StartDate, charindex('-', reverse(StartDate))-1)
             else StartDate
        end) as lastone FROM [kneipp].[dbo].[kn_projects]
```

got **`2013 15:02:40 and 2011 10:11:20`**

How to achieve my expected result

Comment: what's the type of column StartDate ?

Comment: It is of type varchar.......varchar(50)

Comment: Is it always formated like "dd-mm-yyyy"? Why not just do `substring(startdate,7,4)` then?

Comment: @JakubKania That was a nice solution. Using with DISTINCT it worked fine.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try expression like this?

```
SELECT distinct year( convert(datetime,StartDate,105)) 
FROM [kneipp].[dbo].[kn_projects]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can CAST the column into a DATETIME format

```
SELECT YEAR(CAST(StartDate AS DATETIME)) FROM [kneipp].[dbo].[kn_projects]
```

Comment: I thought of that also but feared of some code changes and breakages at many places in my source code

Comment: I understand, but then you will have a very complicated statement which you maybe should do in your application. Or you check the format before inserting

Comment: I am getting an error like "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value." running the query

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you can convert to datetime ,if you want to retain the data type then try the below query

```
Declare @t varchar(50),@t1 varchar(50)
set @t='15-02-2013 15:02:40'

Select left(parsename(replace(@t,'-','.'),1),4)
```

If you have datetime in any format then try the below expression which will return the year in varchar data type

```
Select left(parsename(replace(@t1,'-','.'),1),
            charindex(' ',parsename(replace(@t1,'-','.'),1)))
```